# jquery template create new row every nth item

Tags: jquery-templates

data from server structured like:

```
  var projects= [
        { 
          name: 'project 1', 
          hours: 1,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 1', 
          hours: 2,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 1', 
          hours: 3,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 1', 
          hours: 4,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 1', 
          hours: 5,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 1', 
          hours: 6,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 1', 
          hours: 7,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 2', 
          hours: 1,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 2', 
          hours: 2,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 2', 
          hours: 3,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 2', 
          hours: 4,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 2', 
          hours: 5,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 2', 
          hours: 6,
        },
        { 
          name: 'project 2', 
          hours: 7,
        }
    ];
```

With jquery template how do I created a table with a new row every 7th item?

I want to format like

```
    <table>
    <tr>
<td>project 1
    <td>hours 1</td>
    <td>hours 2</td>
    <td>hours 3</td>
    <td>hours 4</td>
    <td>hours 5</td>
    <td>hours 6</td>
    <td>hours 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>project 2</td>
    <td>hours 1</td>
    <td>hours 2</td>
    <td>hours 3</td>
    <td>hours 4</td>
    <td>hours 5</td>
    <td>hours 6</td>
    <td>hours 7</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```