# Using KnockoutJs to generate a table with clause to create a new row every so many items using inline templates

Tags: javascript, html, templates, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Can someone show me how to create a table in knockout for an observableArray for a viewModel like below:

I know you use a foreach binding and all that, but I need to create a new TR row every 5 array items. I need the table to only be so far across and have aligned checkbox items basically. I got it to work without tables just adding a bunch of checkboxes to a div (but the checkboxes weren't all lined up), but I want a table to keep things lined up in cells nicely.

Here is an article I posted with some code I did, but I was attempting to put them all in one TR but that won't work and here is another guy trying to do something similar but not using knockout...

I know how to do what I want using regular jquery and external template engine, but I am trying to keep away from jquery if there is a nice knockout binding template way of doing it all.

I might add some bootstrap classes to the table stuff to but not sure, I am using this framework for other parts of my website too. But more focus on the knockout stuff.

[Article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487209/knockoutjs-table-inline-template-troubles/14488570#14488570)

[Article 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349672/jquery-template-create-new-row-every-nth-item)

```
function someModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([]); 
}
```

array items are a class like this :

```
function item(name, id) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = name;
    self.Id = id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need more complex data structuring I recommend using a dependent observable to do it. I'm assuming you want a series of rows each with up to 5 tds.

```
function someModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.items_grouped = ko.computed(function(){
        var grouped = [];
        var itemlist = self.items();
        for(var i = 0; i < itemlist.length; i+=5){
            var row = [];
            grouped.push(row);
            for(var j = 0; j < 5; ++j){
                row.push(itemlist[i+j]);
            }
        }
        return grouped;
    });
}

<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items_grouped">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: Id"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can of course make the clustering implementation cleaner using whatever libraries you have on hand.
On a side note, using tables for layouts is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I will try this out. But why is using tables a bad idea for layout. What else and how could I get a bunch of checkboxes to line up not using tables?

Comment: Also how often will the code call this computed observable? Seems like it will call it often because the computed observable is the top most binding, so knockoutjs would have to keep calling it every few seconds to make sure it had the right computed list.

Comment: Is there a way to make the dependentObservable dependent on the items array changing? By the way dependentObservable is now ko.computed

Comment: You need to read up on how ko.computed works. The gist of it is because I'm accessing self.items() inside the computed function, knockout knows that there is a dependency, and will only recompute it when self.items changes. The whole story is more complicated, but in general you can trust it to work out correctly, and without any polling.

Comment: As for layout, there's many different ways to do it. My css-fu is weak, but floats can do the job, amongst others.

Comment: Ok I will try it out and look into non table aligning.

Comment: I can't make this work that I took from your code..http://jsfiddle.net/WWAyN/  ??